# Fix unmet dependencies libc-bin

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies, paths

I am trying to install some programs, but I met with unmet dependencies.
For example, `sudo apt-get upgrade` yields

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: libc-bin (>= 2.13)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Using `sudo apt-get -f install` outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,168 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,529 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

As root, I edited the `/etc/sudoers.tmp` file, and my path does include `/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does your PATH also include /usr/bin?

Comment: My path is `secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`, so I don't understand the error.

Comment: @Stouty Welcome to Ask Ubuntu , Could you [edit] the question and add output of `echo 1 $PATH; sudo echo 2 $PATH;` . Another point, try switch to root using  `su -` and see if you can install it from there.